# Convert server response (std::string) into a png file

Tags: c++, string, image, curl, png

I'm getting a response from a server using boost::asio. The result is stored in a std::string.

I want to convert this std::string into a .png image and write it to file.

I'm having awful trouble with this. Here is my code:

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
std::string errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
std::string url="http://www.google.ie/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
std::string response="";

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_to_string);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

res=curl_easy_perform(curl);

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

response now stored in `response`

```
write_to_binary_file(response.data());
```

, where write_to_binary_file is:

```
void write_to_binary_file(std::string p_Data){
        //std::fstream binary_file("./img.png",std::ios::out|std::ios::binary|std::ios::app);
        //binary_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&p_Data),sizeof(std::string));
        //binary_file.close();
        std::ofstream file("img.png", std::ios::binary);
        file.write(p_Data,sizeof(p_Data));
        file.close();
}
```

Now if I do an octal dump on the file written by my C++ program, it's totally different to the octal dump I get when I download the file from the URL directly.

---

Updated write_to_binary_file

```
int write_to_binary_file(const char* p_Data){
        //std::fstream binary_file("./img.png",std::ios::out|std::ios::binary|std::ios::app);
        //binary_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&p_Data),sizeof(std::string));
        //binary_file.write(c_str(),sizeof(ring));
        //binary_file.close();
        /*std::ofstream file("img.png", std::ios::binary);
        file.write(p_Data,len);
        file.close();*/
        FILE *fp;
        size_t count;
        const char *str = p_Data;

        fp = fopen("img.png", "w");
        if(fp == NULL) {
                perror("failed to open img.png");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        count = fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), fp);
        printf("Wrote %zu bytes. fclose(fp) %s.\n", count, fclose(fp) == 0 ? "succeeded" : "failed");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Call using `int x=write_to_binary_file(response.c_str());`

Still won't work for me ;(

Comment: The declaration of `errorBuffer` and the line `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer);` don't make sense. Re-read the manual for that function.

Comment: `sizeof(std::string)` is so wrong. Did you use `reinterpret_cast` because the compiler was like "OH GOD NO DON'T CAST p_Data TO THAT"?

Comment: @todda.speot.is Yeah, I pulled it off the interweb... Could you make a suggestion as to how to fix?

Comment: what is "response"? why are you casting it to string?

Comment: Hi Alessandro - "response" is a std::string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
binary_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&p_Data),sizeof(std::string));
```

Right, this is why `reinterpret_cast` is poor in many scenarios: it promotes *guesscoding*.

This is when you've thrown away your reference materials and just assumed that you need to pass a pointer to an `std::string` somewhere, and decided that the compiler's error messages were wrong. So, you used `reinterpret_cast` to "shut it up", and now you're wondering why nothing's working properly.

Presumably somebody has told you to "use `std::string`" instead of char arrays, and you've just swapped the type names rather than doing any research into what the *actual* difference is.

`std::string` is an object with various internal members, and which usually stores its actual string data indirectly (dynamically, or what you may inaccurately and misleadingly refer to as "on the heap"); in fact, it's completely abstracted away from you as to just how it stores its data. Either way, it's not just a `char` array.

Use the API that it provides to obtain a pointer to a `char` array, with either `std::string::data()` or possibly `std::string::c_str()` ... and [stop guesscoding](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

---

Also, I doubt that this compiles:

```
std::string errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer);
```

And you probably wanted to construct a `std::string` with a certain length:

```
std::string errorBuffer(CURL_ERROR_SIZE);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, &errorBuffer[0]);
// ^ (requires C++11 to be completely safe)
```

**Strings are objects, not raw arrays!**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Yes, I'm guilty of guess-coding, but I'm a bit of a C++ noob tbqh... I've edited my post with the updated code...

Comment: @Eamorr: My answer stands. Your updated code doesn't change it.

Comment: Hey Tomalak, thanks for getting back to me. I've updated the OP yet again. The octal dump of img.png is different to the octal dump if I download the file directly. I simply cannot get to the bottom of this on my own.

Comment: @Eamorr: I think a chatroom would be better suited to resolve this if you are after iterative debugging support. I have laid out the facts above which should give you a good starting point. Unfortunately you're _still_ treating `std::string` as if it were an array, completely ignoring the API functions it lovingly provides for you. `file.write(p_Data,sizeof(p_Data));` was close. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: @Eamorr: Instead, get a book from [this list of recommended reading](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) and do not write another line of code until you have it to hand.

Comment: Yes, good point. I have an open question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676223/simple-proxy-using-c-boostasio-libcurl-cant-download-images There's 250 points a-going... Do you think you could help me some more? Thanks,

Comment: @Eamorr: It's the same issue. You're using `std::string` horribly incorrectly, in the same place, in both questions.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that "reinterpret_cast(&p_Data)"
is messing up your data.  Why do you cast it in this way? 
p_Data.data() or p_Data.c_str() are probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) for such a task, given it [deals with HTTP](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/network-http.php) and greatly simplifies the task. I've personally used it download .GIF images from a website.

To address your question (I am admittedly not familiar with boost::asio), the things you will want to consider is:

1. Don't do sizeof(std::string). Std::string has a .size() method. So response.size(); is applicable here.
2. Don't use strlen(), sizeof() or any method that uses a null-terminated sentinel value when dealing with raw data from a website, as a null-value can occur *anywhere* in the raw data stream (it isn't like text). Use std::string's .size() method.
3. Given it's raw data, write in binary mode! Text mode will terminate on the ctrl+z signal within a file on windows. IE it'd likely not fully write the file.
4. Base64 doesn't always apply. Chances are this is automated anyway.
5. Consider extracting the filename from the supplied URL itself.

Assuming response is acceptable, this is the code you want:

```
FILE * File = NULL;
File = fopen("Image.png","wb"); //Note b for binary mode
if(File == NULL){return 1;} //Error
if(fwrite(response.c_str(),response.size(),1,File) != response.size()) //If there is a mismatch between the amount of data written and the string size, we have an error
{
    perror("File write error occurred"); //Needs errno
    fclose(File);
    return 2;
}

fclose(File);
```

Answer (score -1):

look what is the contents of your responce string.
probably you should decode it by base64 decoder before writing into file

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the reply. Is a base64 conversion really necessary? I printed out the response string to the console and it looks like a normal PNG image. Could you please tell me how to decode into base64? Many thanks,

Comment: not "into" but "from". The binary data transmitted over http is encoded to base64 to avoid using non-printable characters. This is the limitation of http. But I don't know whether Curl does decode itself or no. Probably no, if it uses std::string to handle the responce

Comment: do you know of any way to get around this?

Comment: my previous edit didn't saved. Look here for source of decoder  http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html